# Playing with squares

Tags: square-numbers

Extending from particular examples I've found that $$n^2=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} 2\, i+n$$
this is that for any square of side $n$ the area can be calculated in a simple way.

**Example**

For a square of side $7$, the result is: $2×1+2×2+2×3+\cdots + 7=49$

**Question**

Is there any way to prove this generally true, is there more than one way?Can you show at least one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A visual proof. A variant of the one found in the book "Proofs Without Words"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Permuting your equation, i.e. moving $n$ to the left, and dividing by $2$, yields the equivalent equation

$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i$$ which is a very well known equation that can easily be proven by induction. Or just look at how [Gauss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Kp4EOm3xII) did it when he was a child.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sum can be written as a [telescopic sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html):
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 2 i+n&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (2 i+1)+1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} ((i+1)^2-i^2)+1\\
&=(n^2-1)+1=n^2.
\end{align}$$
Similarly, we can show
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (3i^2+3i)+n=n^3\quad\text{or}\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (4i^3+6i^2+4i)+n=n^4.
$$

Comment: wow, it is just impressive. there is something strange in the first equality, though...

Comment: @santimirandarp Yes, you are right. I fixed it.

Comment: Nice! Now the last number appears correctly.  But I found the (2i + 1) difficult notation, do you? Maybe it's just a matter of habit...

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}1$ means the sum of $n-1$ times the number $1$, that is $n-1$.

Comment: Yes, so the mistake is supposing it needs an argument like $i$. Don't know where it comes from. Thanks again.

Comment: Using substitution, it seems like $n^k$ can be written as simple sums of products.  Wonder what that would look like...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1} 2\, i\,+n=2\left(\dfrac {n (n-1)}2\right)+n=n^2$$